# Setting dataframe values in range of dates specified in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables:

1. A three-level index of stock symbols `cik`, buy dates `t0`, and sell dates `t1`.
2. A blank position DataFrame with range of dates in the index column and stock symbols across the columns.

I need to iterate through the first index, and set all of the values in the position matrix to 1 where the date is in the range of `[t0, t1]` to `1`. The rest should be left at zero.

**Sell Index `sell_idx`**

```
MultiIndex([('AAPL', '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13'),
            ( 'IBM', '2020-03-13', '2020-03-16')],
           )
```

**Position Matrix `pos`**

```
            FB  AAPL  IBM
2020-03-12   0     0    0
2020-03-13   0     0    0
2020-03-16   0     0    0
```

**Expected output**

```
            FB  AAPL  IBM
2020-03-12   0     1    0
2020-03-13   0     1    1
2020-03-16   0     0    1
```

I have done this successfully iteratively and frankly it's not even that slow:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    (
        ('AAPL', pd.Timestamp('2020-03-12'), pd.Timestamp('2020-03-13'))
        , ('IBM', pd.Timestamp('2020-03-13'), pd.Timestamp('2020-03-16'))
    )
)

pos = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['FB', 'AAPL', 'IBM']
                   , index=[pd.Timestamp('2020-03-12')
                   , pd.Timestamp('2020-03-13')
                   , pd.Timestamp('2020-03-16')])

for i in idx:
    pos.loc[i[1]:i[2], i[0]] = 1
```

I would like to vectorize this code. How would I use advanced pandas slicing/indexing to do this without `apply` or `for`?

Comment: What is your expected output for the sample input? Not sure what the column names in `pos` are supposed to represent

Comment: If sell_idx consists of `(1800, '2020-03-12', '2020-03-13')` then expected output for `pos` would be `2020-03-12   0 1 0  2020-03-13   0 1 0 2020-03-16   0 0 0`

Comment: I think apply would arguably be less readable than what I already have, as you can't use assignment in a lambda function. So my guess is it won't improve performance or readability?

Comment: kindly provide the multiindex as code: `pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples...` or dictionary, or sometihing reproducible

Comment: ok, updated the post with fully reproducible code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Build an interval index; luckily your data does not have overlaps:

```py
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(idx.get_level_values(1), 
                                         idx.get_level_values(-1), 
                                         closed="both" )
```

Get matches:

```py
arr = intervals.get_indexer(pos.index)
```

Create new dataframe:

```py
index = [pos.index, idx.get_level_values(0)[arr]]
mapping = pd.Series([1] * len(arr), index = index).unstack(fill_value = 0)
```

Get columns, if any that does not exist in `mapping`:

```py
difference = pos.columns.difference(mapping.columns)
```

Join to `pos` to get the final output:

```py
pos.filter(difference).join(mapping, how="left")

            FB  AAPL  IBM
2020-03-12   0     1    0
2020-03-13   0     1    0
2020-03-16   0     0    1
```

This should scale well as the data size increases; note however, that this relies on the intervals not overlapping, and also that there are no duplicates in the data (allowing unstack to work as well)

Comment: Unfortunately the data certainly has overlaps (we may hold more than one stock in the portfolio)... thank you for a thoughtful answer in any case.

Comment: Kindly share an example of overlaps in the date boundaries

Comment: done - there is overlap now